# Merge input sanitation tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sanitization), [sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sanitize), [input-sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-sanitization), and possibly [html-sanitizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-sanitizing) should be merged. With the possible exception of *html-sanitizing*, they are all the same.

Further, [sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sanitizer) could also be misconstrued, though as the description states it doesn't refer to input sanitization.

I would do it myself but there are hundreds of questions.

The question is; which tag do we merge them to?